# What does this error mean 'Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event. Source File'

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, event-handling

I got this error:

```
Exception Description : E:\sites\EPER EN\Admin\DB\DataFilter.ascx.vb(144): error BC32022: 'Public Event Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)' is an event, 
and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event.  Source File :   Line : 0
```

in the following vb.net code :

```
submitFilterButton.Click += New EventHandler(AddressOf submitFilterButtonHandler_Click)
```

What does this error mean ?

Comment: If you want to register an event handler programmatically, you have to use: `AddHandler submitFilterButton.Click AddressOf submitFilterButtonHandler_Click`. You can also add it declaratively either on aspx markup(`OnClick="submitFilterButtonHandler_Click"`) or in codebehind via `Handles submitFilterButton.Click` behind method signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to register an event handler programmatically, you have to use: [`AddHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
AddHandler submitFilterButton.Click, AddressOf submitFilterButtonHandler_Click
```

You can also add it declaratively either on aspx markup ( handler must be protected/public )

```
OnClick="submitFilterButtonHandler_Click"
```

or in codebehind via `Handles` clause ( can be private )

```
Private Sub submitFilterButtonHandler_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles submitFilterButton.Click
```

[**How to: Create Event Handlers in ASP.NET Web Pages**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6w2tb12s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)